# Powerapps list files in sharepoint document set

Tags: document-library, document-set, powerapp

I have a document library which stores multiple document sets, each for a client. In each document set there are multiple files.

In my powerapp, given client ID, how can I list files in a gallery of that client's document set?

The document library has a unique lookup column of client ID, which means one client can only have one document set in the library.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below solution.

I have a list named Clients with a column named "ClientID" which will be used for filtering the Documents in powerapp. This "ClientID" is a lookup column in the *DocumentSetLibrary* (Library which contains your documents inside document sets for each client).

[image]

A PowerApp is created which consists a gallery and an input search text box as shown below. Initially all the documents will be shown in the gallery.

[image]

In the input textbox, please remove the value in `Default`. You can add it to `Hint Text` if you want. Below are screenshots of the formula entered for the gallery `Items`.

In my case, the source to the gallery library that contains the document sets (***DocumentSetLibrary***).

> I have filtered the "DocumentSetLibrary" using "IsFolder" because DocumentSet is nothing but a folder so to NOT display document set names in the gallery, the filter is applied as `"IsFolder" = false`

[image]

Run the app and try it.

[image]

**Note: Please do not forget to replace names of library and fields, with names in your solution.**
Please upvote and mark as answer i it helps. Thanks.

To filter only in 1 document set use the below formula on the gallery

```
If(TextInput1.Text = "", Filter(DocumentSetLibrary, IsFolder = false), Search(Filter(DocumentSetLibrary, IsFolder = false && ClientID.Value = "Client ID which you want to search on"), TextInput1.Text, "{Path}"))
```

Comment: Is there a way to only search files in one document set?

Comment: check the updated answer